# How does firing from behind cover affect accuracy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

**Does firing from behind cover affect weapon accuracy?** I can see this going either way from a "real-life" standpoint. I can see the accuracy increasing and recoil decreasing due to stability provided by a hard slab of material to rest your arms and weapon against. I can also see the accuracy decreasing and recoil increasing due to the awkwardness of posture and the abruptness of popping out of cover to quickly fire off rounds.

**Is this aspect of combat documented anywhere, or has anyone conducted related experiments?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While behind cover accuracy increases, and recoil decreases.

For these reasons, it's always better to fire from behind cover if your enemy is at mid-long range, even with shotguns.

Some weapons are actually really unwieldy if not fired from behind cover due to their extreme recoil (particularly a few smg's).

Comment: what he said...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will find an increase in accuracy, and more controllable recoil. Firing from cover will be more effective and is reccomended with any weapon. Tested on xbox.